# Send a pdf on an default Email Client - Android Aplication

Tags: java, android, email-attachments

I need send a PDF file attach on a message, I have a button that calls a function that open a Intent with message, email address and subject filled, but I need that the PDF file has been attached too.

This is my code and I can not find my error, someone can help me please?

```
 public void initializeWebView() {
        // Initialize the webview

        webView.setResourceClient(new XWalkResourceClient(webView) {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(XWalkView view, String stringUrl) {

                if(stringUrl.equals(baseUrl)) {
                    return false;
                }

                // mailto links will be handled by the OS.
                if (stringUrl.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(stringUrl);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    String fileName = "bouhnik.pdf";
                    String filePath = (Configuration.getMagazineAssetPath()).toString()+ File.separator  + fileName;
                    Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                    File file = null;
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {

                        InputStream is = c.getAssets().open(filePath);

                        int size = is.available();
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                        is.read(buffer);
                        is.close();


                        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        fos.write(buffer);
                        fos.close();


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.i("Ferrou",e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (!file.exists() || !file.canRead()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_STREAM, file.getPath());
                    intent.setClassName("com.android.email", "com.android.mail.compose.ComposeActivity");
                    intent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                    WebViewFragment.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email..."));

                } else {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);


                        // We try to remove the referrer string to avoid passing it to the server in case the URL is an external link.
                        String referrer = "";
                        if (url.getQuery() != null) {
                            Map<String, String> variables = Configuration.splitUrlQueryString(url);
                            String finalQueryString = "";
                            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : variables.entrySet()) {
                                if (entry.getKey().equals("referrer")) {
                                    referrer = entry.getValue();
                                } else {
                                    finalQueryString += entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue() + "&";
                                }
                            }
                            if (!finalQueryString.isEmpty()) {
                                finalQueryString = "?" + finalQueryString.substring(0, finalQueryString.length() - 1);
                            }
                            stringUrl = stringUrl.replace("?" + url.getQuery(), finalQueryString);
                        }
                        // Remove referrer from query string
                        if (!url.getProtocol().equals("file")) {
                            if (referrer.equals(WebViewFragment.this.getActivity().getString(R.string.url_external_referrer))) {
                                Uri uri = Uri.parse(stringUrl);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                                WebViewFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else if (referrer.toLowerCase().equals(WebViewFragment.this.getActivity().getString(R.string.url_baker_referrer))) {
                                ((IssueActivity) WebViewFragment.this.getActivity()).openLinkInModal(stringUrl);
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            stringUrl = url.getPath().substring(url.getPath().lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                            int index = ((IssueActivity) WebViewFragment.this.getActivity()).getJsonBook().getContents().indexOf(stringUrl);
                            if (index != -1) {
                                Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), "Index to load: " + index + ", page: " + stringUrl);
                                ((IssueActivity) WebViewFragment.this.getActivity()).getViewPager().setCurrentItem(index);
                                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            } else {
                                // If the file DOES NOT exist, we won't load it.
                                File htmlFile = new File(url.getPath());
                                if (htmlFile.exists()) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (MalformedURLException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                        Log.d(">>>URL_DATA", ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        // Set UI Client (Start stop animations)
        webView.setUIClient(new XWalkUIClient(webView) {

            @Override
            public void onPageLoadStopped(XWalkView view, String url, LoadStatus status) {
                if(!url.isEmpty() && status == LoadStatus.FINISHED) {
                    if(isUserVisible) {
                        webView.resumeTimers();
                    }else{
                        webView.pauseTimers();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        webView.load(baseUrl, null);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know .-. Always I run now, I receive this exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/android_asset/books/bouhnik.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

Comment: Check that the `uri` resolves to an actual file, and try logging the file content (`Log.d`) in that block of code, to ensure the file contents are actually readable.

Comment: When I got to this line:  try {
                        AssetManager am = c.getAssets();
                      *****  InputStream is = am.open("books/"+fileName);

They give me a Exception "FileNotFound", but I have this path and this file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something is might be going wrong with your file path. Double check it. Then

1 - You need to add the package name of your application with `context.getPackageName()`

```
private String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + context.getPackageName() +  "books/"+fileName;
```

2 - Declare the permission inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank's so much for everyone!!

I solve my problem change the type of Intent to:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

Because this is better to email commands, and I define a emailUri where:

```
emailUri = Uri.fromFile(file.getAbsoluteFile());
```

because this get a absolute path with a file inside, and when the email client open, it open this file, not a path.

I add a type at my intent but I select the type of my attachment, so I define:

```
 emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
```

And finally:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriMail);
 startActivity(emailIntent);
```

It's works now!! Thanks :D